# How to refer to selected jQuery element in another function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

excuse me for my beginner question. Looking at this example:

```
$("#el4").html(`<b>${$("#el4").text()}</b>`);
```

I want to make text of the selected element bold.
At the start of the line I selected $el4, then using html() I will replace the text with `<b></b>` tags.
Between those tags I want to inject the current text of the element, but to do so I have to select the same element again using it's ID $("#el4").

Is it possible to somehow refer to the element that I am already working on? Something other than storing it in variable.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your code appears to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2rzm04uq/. One alternative is `$("#el4").html(function(){return \`<b>${$(this).text()}</b>\`});`

Comment: @epascarello I did. Is there something that isn't clear in my comment (other than the code formatting)?

Comment: Are you doing this in an event listener that's bound to multiple elements? You can use `$(this)` in the listener.

Comment: @j08691 Your original comment was it appears to work fine. And OP knew it worked, they asked for another way to do it.

Comment: @epascarello Actually the code formatting cutoff the end of my original comment. Looks like you replied while I was fixing

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's `.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) accepts a function so you can use that to reference the element. The functions arguments are index and the html string. If you do not want to use the html, you can use `this` and reference the element it is working on.

```js
$("#el4").html(function(_,html){
  return `<b>${html}</b>`;
});


$("#el5").html(function(_,html){
  return `<b>${$(this).text()}</b>`;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="el4">Hello</p>

<p id="el5">WORLD</p>
```

Comment: Yeaah! That's exactly what I was looking for =) thank you for the explanation. For the future I have to search for the arguments the function can take.

Answer (score 0):

So this code as @epascarello said does work:

```
$("#el4").html(function(){ return `<b>${$(this).text()}</b>`; });
```

but the same code with an arrow function doesn't:

```
$("#el5").html(() => `<b>${$(this).text()}</b>`);
```

Arrow function does in fact work when I select this element manually again using `$("#el5")`. Does that mean keyword this is pointing at different things in regular function and arrow function? Gotta read up on this..

Thanks to everyone that answered so quickly. It's my first post on stackoverflow and I am amazed by the response =)